# Remote desktop issue over VPN connection Windows 8 and now 10

Tags: windows, vpn, remote-desktop, windows-8.1, windows-10

I have recently reinstalled Windows 8 Pro and upgraded to Windows 10 Pro. Both operating systems had this issue.

When I connect to the VPN connection at my workplace, I am able to successfully remote desktop to my work computer.

After a while (10-30 minutes) my remote desktop connection will freeze or disconnect. Attempting to reconnect my remote desktop session will result in me receiving the computer not found message. If I disconnect, and then reconnect the VPN connection then I am able to reconnect to remote desktop until it freezes again.

Has anyone experienced this, or do you know of anything I could try?

Comment: Try running Ping -t during a session and see if it still times out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your VPN connection is timing out.  Probably an "inactivity" setting on the firewall that is not recognizing RDP traffic as VPN activity.

I've also seen where VPN is very sensitive to lost or dropped packets. While RDP is rather resilient to lost packets for some reason RDP running over VPN is overly sensitive and will disconnect often.  I suggest looking into your modem or router.  If the problem cannot be replicated with another computer in the network it's possibly even a NIC or wiring problem.

On windows I like to use PING with -l option to increase packet size to at least 1024 and -t option to keep it running.  On a good VPN connection you should have far less than 1% packet loss.  (Speed/Latency is not so much an issue with RDP.)
Ping: 1) internal (gateway router), 2) external (i.e. google), 3) over VPN (remote router or server) so you can tell where the failure is happening.  E.g. It could be WiFi problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I upgraded the VPN in my workplace from PPTP to IKEv2 and I think this cleared up the problem. I think its quite likely your suggestions would have helped me track it down.